# Add UINavigationController to subview on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been trying to add this UINavigationController to a subview of my form... All I am getting is a large grey screen.

```
LiteViewController *lite = [[LiteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LiteViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:lite.navigationController.view];
```

It should add a full screen navigation controller to the current view.

Answer (score 1):

I found a post, *[UINavigationController not showing the Root View controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909660/uinavigationcontroller-not-showing-the-root-view-controller)*, that worked for me.

Basically you also need to set the view of the navigationController...

```
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
[navigationController setView:[[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need a makeKeyAndVisible call.

Comment: To my understanding, the window is visible because I can add other things to the subview and it will work... just this navigationController is giving me a headache.

Comment: I'm just getting started with iPhone development, but all the examples I've seen add navigation controllers straight to a UIWindow and not UIView. Maybe, given the full screen nature of this control, it wants to be added to a window? See Apple's docs here too: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW1