# UINavigationController not showing the Root View controller

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios4, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIView (menuView in code below) of size 320x218 inside a view. I want to load a navigation controller into this view. Im using the following code to do that:

```
MenuViewController *menuController = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:menuController];
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

[menuView addSubview:navigationController.view];
[menuController release];
[navigationController release];
```

When I execute it, the root view is not displayed in that view. Only a navigation bar is displayed and the rest of the view is empty.

**Edit:**

I just placed an NSLog() in both initWithNibName: and viewDidLoad: of MenuViewController. The one in initWithNibName: gets called but the one in viewDidLoad: doesn't :S

**Update:**

I tried to push `menuController` to my `navigationController` thinking since its not appearing, it might not be on the stack. Exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported
```

Comment: Does MenuViewController.xib exist and the name is correct?

Comment: Yes and yes. I just placed an NSLog() in both initWithNibName: and viewDidLoad: of MenuViewController. The one in initWithNibName: gets called but the one in viewDidLoad: doesn't :S

Comment: Ok after reading your comment, can you place a line menuController.view; after you create the  navigationController? Just add that line and let me know the result.

Comment: just like menuController.view; or put it in NSLog()???

Comment: Just add that line as part of code, you will get a warning but thats ok.

Comment: Nothing happened. Got the warning like you said but no exceptions or errors when executed

Comment: Is menuView a view or a view controller?

Comment: Can you add another view to the navcontroller?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? If not we can continue over chat to discuss in detail.

Comment: @PraveenS let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2087/discussion-between-xs2bush-and-praveen-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here:

[UIViewController -viewDidLoad not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913627/uiviewcontroller-viewdidload-not-being-called)

I had to add these lines of code after `-initWithRootViewController` in order to load the view of my root view Controller:

```
navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
[navigationController setView:menuController.view];
```

Answer (score 8):

call layoutsubviews do work.

```
[super loadView];
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
[navigationController.view layoutSubviews];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the navigationViewController as an subview To your MenuViewController.
As the navigationViewController already already holds the MenuViewController.

Just display the navigationViewController.

Comment: menuView is not an object of menuViewController its an object of UIView

Answer (score 0):

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

ViewController *viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];

self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
```

Try this code in your appdelegate method